# JavaScript: call toggle function on all href on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a help page with a bunch of javascript toggles to show or hide help for the topic. Is there a way to toggle them all to show all or hide all?

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('roles');">Roles or Account Permissions</a>
    <div id="roles" style="display:none">

<a href="javascript:toggle('tracks');">Tracks and Activities</a>
    <div id="tracks" style="display:none">

<a href="javascript:toggle('password');">Modifying Password</a>
    <div id="password" style="display:none">
```

Like maybe

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('roles', 'tracks', 'password');">Toggle all</a>
```

Here is my javascript

```
function toggle(divId) {
"use strict";
var div = document.getElementById(divId);
if (div.style.display === "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
} else {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript code?

Comment: Give them all the same class, and use `$(".classname")` to operate on all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop though all ids using `arguments` collection:

```
function toggle() {
    "use strict";
    [].slice.call(arguments).forEach(function(divId) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if (div.style.display === "none") {
            div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        } 
    });
}
```

I converted `arguments` to pure array for convenience (to use `Array.prototype.forEach` method), you can use simple `for` loop of course too.

Check the demo below.

```js
function toggle() {
    "use strict";
    [].slice.call(arguments).forEach(function(divId) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if (div.style.display === "none") {
            div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        } 
    });
}
```

```css
a {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:toggle('roles');">Roles or Account Permissions</a>
<div id="roles" style="display:none">Roles</div>
    
<a href="javascript:toggle('tracks');">Tracks and Activities</a>
<div id="tracks" style="display:none">Tracks</div>
        
<a href="javascript:toggle('password');">Modifying Password</a>
<div id="password" style="display:none">Modifying Password</div>

<a href="javascript:toggle('roles', 'tracks', 'password');">Toggle all</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the jQuery tag so it sounds like you are using jQuery?

Add a class name to each A tag then:

```
<a href="javascript:$('a.className').toggle();">toggle</a>
```

No need for your toggle code.